# Autorun.inf on a usb can you get it to run a pdf?

Tags: pdf, autorun

I've done some research all over the net,  I guess I am just looking for conformation.

Due to how Microsoft has put security on autorun in vista and above. Autorun from a usb no longer works. Correct?  It seems like it will still bring up the options to run .exe but for some odd reason I cannot get it to run a .pdf. This [site](http://lazybit.com/index.php/2007/03/01/usb_flash_drive_autorun) has suggested that I load up a pdf reader and run that and then call it to run the pdf.   But a generic pdf reader  would still have to go through the install prior to running it, something I am trying to avoid.

The other idea I came up with was cause of this specialty usb manufactures have stated that they their usb drives can autorun files because they are formated to be local disks.

So after some experimenting and doing [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_5941768_make-flash-drive-local-disk.html) I converted my usb to a local to see if that would work and pasting the autorun.inf in there with the correct code...

```
[AutoRun]
shellexecute=mypdf.pdf 
icon=mypdf.ico 
label=mypdf
```

sadly it does't work

Also after thinking about it creating a local disk would only work with the driver software that I loaded up onto that usb... so say it is a 64bit and the client has a 32bit it wont run. (right?)

Can someone just confirm that there is no way to autorun a pdf from a usb? or even have it as an option to select from when it is plugged in for the first time. I cannot believe I have spent an entire day trying to just get autorun to work.

Thanks for taking the time to read this nub question

Comment: I haven't tried this: how about creating a batch script file .bat that call a pdf reader with argument to the pdf file in it? Then pass `shellexecute=script.bat` in autorun.inf

Comment: If that is not possible, how about `shellexecute=AcroRd32.exe mypdf.pdf`?

Comment: I tried that with open=script.bat guess I'll see if it works with shellexecute

Answer (score 2):

Try using a PDF viewer which does not require installation, eg:

```
http://www.snapfiles.com/get/sumatrapdf.html
```

From this site:

```
http://www.snapfiles.com/features/ed_usb_software.html
```

Comment: maybe I'm still doing it wrong but then wouldn't the code be           
    [autorun]
    OPEN=SumatraPDF.exe mypdf.pdf
    ICON=mypdf.ico
    ACTION= mypdf

Comment: Yeah, or you could point it to a bat file which contains the executable and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using sumatraPDF portable installation you can launch that from the flash drive.

The way I did it is by creating autorun.inf with the following:

```
[autorun]
icon=autorun.ico
label=Label for Drive
action=Action Description
open=autorun.bat
```

And a autorun.bat file with the following:

```
start SumatraPDF.exe ../pdfname.pdf
```

**However, if the user has autorun turned off it will not work and in Windows 7 and above autorun functionality for flash drives is restricted to label and icon only.**