# Autorun PDF on CD

Tags: windows, pdf, cd, autorun

I need to burn a CD which contains a PDF which my clients wants to autorun. I tried Autorun.inf with

```
[autorun]
open=MyPDFfile.pdf
shellexecute=MyPDFfile.pdf
```

And I tried a Autorun.inf with start.bat with

```
[autorun]
open=start.bat
```

and

```
start=MyPDFfile.pdf
```

But no luck, both just give me the popup to open the cd in explorer, not even the PDF in the menu.

Does anyone has any help?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with just an Autorun.inf but after some investigation I found this http://www.hamradiousa.net/compactautorunner.html Compact AutoRunner, which creates the Autorun.inf and an .exe for you from which you can start the .pdf and the .exe will come up in the popup menu after inserting the CD. Client was pleased with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [guide](http://www.autoruntools.com/autorun-inf-doc-html-pdf-ppt.php)...

Have you tried:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=MyPDFfile.pdf
```

This guy seems to be having a similar problem - [Autorun.inf on a usb can you get it to run a pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499059/autorun-inf-on-a-usb-can-you-get-it-to-run-a-pdf)

The only answer provided says to include a freely distributable PDF viewer exe with the CD/USB